# How to using guard and condition in iOS Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, conditional-statements, guard

I wanna to get result of function and set it in another variable(*let* or *var*) and then check it with a condition like this:

```
guard galleryArr:Array<UIImage> = fetchGalleryImages() , galleryArr.count  != 0 {

}else{

}
```

Please tell me the right way to fix this.

Comment: How is fetchGalleryImages() defined? Does it return an array or an optional array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**

you can user guard and where condition like below:

But it must be that `fetchGalleryImages()` return `optional` value.

```
guard let galleryArr = fetchGalleryImages(), galleryArr.count > 0 else { 
 //What ever condition you want to do on fail or simply return 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func doSomething() -> Int? {
    guard let galleryArr = fetchGalleryImages(), galleryArr.count != 0 else {
        // you must return from doSomething in here, be it by throwing
        // a fatalError(), return nil, or some other value to indicate
        // that the call has failed
        return nil
    }

    // proceed with the function
    return ...
}
```